# Dynamic StringFormat on XAML TextBox via a property on the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I have a XAML view with 10 TextBox bound to 10 properties on my ViewModel.  Each of those properties on my ViewModel have a corresponding property to SignificantDigits value.  IE  PropertyA has a significant digit value of 2.  PropertyB has a significant digit value of 4.   Therefore within the UI i want to display PropertyA as 1.12 and PropertyB as 1.4312.

Is there a way using StringFormat to bind to the SignificantDigit value on the VM to limit the number of decimal places shown?

Example.

```
PropertyA = 1.231231;
PropertyB = 1.234234;

PropertyASignificantDigits = 2;
PropertyBSignificant Digits = 4;

<TextBox  Text="{Binding PropertyA, StringFormat={}{0:{PropertyASignificantDigits}}" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

The UI would then display 1.23 for PropertyA

Id prefer not to use a converter if i can manage it from within the xaml

Comment: Please provide the code example. I can't catch the idea. What is your objective? By the way, here's [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: You can't bind the StringFormat property of a Binding. A possible approach would be a MultiBinding with an IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: i went ahead and updated with an example.  Im hoping to keep it within the UI and not use a converter if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a MultiBinding and a IMultiValueConverter.

The MultiBinding takes in your value and number of decimal places and then uses a custom multi value converter to do a `string.Format` on the value, returning the result.

Here is a simple example:

XAML

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DecimalPlaceStringFormatConverter}">
            <Binding Path="PropertyAValue" />
            <Binding Path="PropertyADecimalPlaces" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Converter

```
public class DecimalPlaceStringFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string result = null;

        if (values.Length == 2 && values[0] is double value && values[1] is int decimalPlaces)
        {
            result = string.Format($"{{0:F{decimalPlaces}}}", value);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: im hoping to keep it within the UI and not use a converter if at all possible.  This will definitely work with a converter

Comment: You can't do it all in XAML. You have two choices. Do it in code-behind, or use a converter.

Comment: Perfect than thats exactly what i wanted to know and hear

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Keithernet the answer for me was that you cannot do this within XAML directly and needed to use a converter.  Using his answer, this is how my final converter looks

```
public class DecimalPlaceStringFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert( object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
        {
            if( !decimal.TryParse( values[ 0 ].ToString(), out decimal value ) )
                return values[ 0 ].ToString();

            if( !int.TryParse( values[ 1 ].ToString(), out int decimalPlaces ) )
                return value;

            if( values.Length == 2 )
                return string.Format( $"{{0:F{decimalPlaces}}}", value );
            else
                return value;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack( object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture )
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```